# Are there any public and opensource TeX/LaTeX related projects hosted on GitHub?

Tags: packages, git

Today I read on GitHub's website that membership and using GitHub for public and opensource projects is free.

Are there any opensource and public TeX/LaTeX related projects available on GitHub in which users may involve and contribute in TeX coding?

Also, are there any other collaborative TeX code developing websites which are optimized for TeX/LaTeX projects?

Comment: Isn't this a bit open-ended for the format here? There are certainly lots and there is a [list on meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3821/who-has-a-github-bitbucket-other-code-profile) of  people here with GitHub profiles (and who've posted the data).

Comment: I would say, many (not all) (La)TeX package developers use github somehow and many users of TeX.SX have a github profile link in their TeX.SX profile page ;-) However, I doubt it's useful to make everything public

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think a lot of developers have no public source control or indeed no source control at all: there are a _lot- of packages on CTAN of which a small number of 'active' ones pop up here or on GitHub

Comment: @JosephWright: As I said: Many, not all. I have a github account too, but I didn't make it public (or better: it's not public any longer!)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer why *better*?

Comment: Are you interested in developing? I'm doing a Liederbuch and Liederheft package. Want to join? - I know, this is more chat related.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: 'better' in the sense that I am clearifing my statement.

Comment: Just go here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here Projects hosted in GitHub have the little icon near the package name.

Comment: plus all of mine and several of Heiko's which aren't listed there as github:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's exactly why I asked my question. There maybe some opensource projects which may not be listed in the lists linked above, some projects may still be in their early stages and not introduced yet, etc.

Comment: I think it's too broad for this site https://github.com/search?q=latex says We’ve found 14,656 repository results  and they can't all be http://i.stack.imgur.com/RCo7s.jpg

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, but not all of these search results are active projects; as a huge number of those were last updated at least a year ago.

Comment: shrug: `longtable` was last updated over 25 years ago, but it doesn't mean change requests are not accepted.